# Export from GCP BigQuery to parquet: How to get proper scale, precision of numeric type?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, parquet, pyarrow

I have a column A of type `NUMERIC(29)` in `tableA` in BQ. I export it to parquet using BigQueryToGCSOperator:

```
transferBigQueryToBucket = BigQueryToGCSOperator(
    task_id='BigQueryToBucket'
        ,source_project_dataset_table= xyz
        ,compression="GZIP"
        ,destination_cloud_storage_uris=xyz
        ,location=xyz
        ,export_format="Parquet"
        ,force_rerun=True)
```

and read it in with pyspark.

I ran into a problem because spark sees that table as

```
StructType([StructField('columnA', DecimalType(38,9), True])
```

I thought it may be a problem with either the airflow operator or with spark, so I exported the data directly from BQ:

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  format='PARQUET',
  uri='gs://address',
  overwrite=true
)
AS
SELECT columnA
FROM tableA
```

and read it in with python, pyarrow - so no airflow, no spark here.

And I got:

```
optional fixed_len_byte_array(16) field_id=-1 columnA (Decimal(precision=38, scale=9));
```

It causes a problem, because I receive numbers like 213123123132.00000000 in my spark dataframe, and as a result I get these zeroes in the csv.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Provide a separate schema for the table - but it would add a lot of work to my workflow and I was hoping to avoid it, as parquet is supposed to hold the schema in the metadata.
2. Some sort of a spark function/UDF that will remove those 0 (i need a generic solution though, not specific to tableA), but I see many problems here - what is the condition, i.e. which records to modify, which function to use etc. Not to mention efficiency of this approach.

None of these solutions address the problem directly - wrong information in the metadata (or maybe python/pyspark's problem with reading this metadata).

I'd appreciate any advice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a limit of parameterized types [within queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#parameterized_data_types).  From the docs:

`A data type's parameters are not propagated in an expression, only the data type is.`

In this case if you want to preserve types in Spark you may try using the [BigQuerySparkConnector](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#parameterized_data_types) to transfer the data directly which makes an effort to preserve the parameterization. I don't know enough about airflow about how to set this up inside of that environment.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use grpc, that's why i can't use these spark-gcp connectors.